# how to use java fx - source code in netbeans

Tags: java, javafx

I have downloaded the JavaFx sample source codes and examined "Ensemble" codes. I have some interest on working on those animations, however when I have copied the source code and pasted into Netbeans, I get the following error.
-JavaFX deployment library not found.

I am not too familiar with Java, so would you please tell me how to integrate the codes into my own project? I think that I could not load the libraries.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you have an older version of JavaFX installed and NetBeans is using this as "Default JavaFX Platform" (see NB-Menu Tools|Java Platforms) ?

The newest Ensemble is using the Canvas and this is not supported with older JavaFX (<2.2).

In this case deinstall all old versions and get the new Java7 with integrated JavaFX Runtime here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/index.html

Comment: i have de-installed all java platforms and reinstalled them. There are 2 Java platforms as jdk1.7.0_02 and jdk1.7.0_07. I use both of them but error still remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to copy and paste the source codes yourself. In Netbeans click to "*Open Project...*" and navigate to `<javafx_sample_dir>/src` directory where the Ensemble will be detected as a Netbeans project. If you are interested in a particular component or feature, just run the Ensemble application and open the related component page and click the "*Save NetBeans Project...*" button then you can open it in Netbeans.
If you still facing that error try first to create a new javaFX project and run it in Netbeans.

Comment: Detected JavaFX Ant API version 1.0
C:\Users\xxx\Documents\NetBeansProjects\button\nbproject\jfx-impl.xml:382: Error:
JavaFX deployment library not found.

This error is constant when I do exactly the same you have explained. Besides, I have created a new project and use the same code to avoid this error, but there is no change. I am suspecting of JavaFX SDK. After I have downloaded and installed the SDK, will there be anything more that I should do?

Comment: You need to define new Java/JavaFX platform (or update existing one) in Netbeans.